# looking for some samples to embed media player into html

Tags: html, silverlight, user-interface, media-player

I am developing some html pages which embed media player (Windows Media Player and Silverlight player, like sl12videoplayer from codeplex http://sl2videoplayer.codeplex.com/ ). I have learned how to embed players into html, by using DIV/OBJECT tags. I have proved it works technically.

My question is, I want to find and learn some samples about how to embed player within web page to have a good layout. The scenario I need to develop is some text based news page and I want to embed some players for videos (related to the news). Any reference samples which have elegant and sample layout to recommend? My confusions are like should I use tr/td, use iframe, frameset? How to set the width/height property to display video in an elegant way and extensible enough for the future?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

I would use CSS for your layout. Look at the source code of YouTube for an example. This is exactly like laying out any other media player on a page (Flash Player, QuickTime, etc.)

Comment: Youtube seems a bit complex, any simple examples? Or any ways to just pick what I need from Youtube home page?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the Windows SDK from msdn.microsoft.com, and then, on your harddisk, look in this directory

\Samples\multimedia\WMP\webpages\embedded

for a simple javasript example.